# Does EmberJS supports KendoUI grid?

Tags: jquery, ember.js, jqgrid, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am creating an application using EmberJS. I need to create a grid using KendoUI as like as http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/remote-data.html . Is it advisable to use Kendo grid in Ember application? or Is there anyother option other than Kendo UI grid?

Your comments are welcome!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check out [Ember Table](https://github.com/Addepar/ember-table). I've used it a couple of times, pretty sweet.